# Determing an inverse Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

> The inverse Fourier transform is defined as:
>
> $$\mathcal{F}^{-1}[g](x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(k) e^{i k x} d k$$

I can't get an inverse Fourier Transform to

> Q1: $$g(k)=\cos (\sqrt{ k^2 d -a^2 })$$
> Q2:
> $$g(k)=\frac{1}{ \sqrt{ k^2 d -a^2 }}\sin (\sqrt{ k^2 d -a^2 })$$

I would really appreciate some any help .

Comment: why would you need a closed form expression for the Fourier transform of those complicated function ?

Comment: have you tried mathematica or stuff like that?

Comment: No. 
Is Mathematica obtain the result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1:
$$
\mathcal{F}^{-1}[g](x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos (\sqrt{ k^2 d -a^2 }) e^{i k x} d k
$$
I see no reason to think it may be written any simpler than that.
Also note that the integrand involves cosine of an imaginary argument, at least on part of the range.

Comment: Do you mean that i should write $2 \cos(\theta)= Re \quad( e^{i \theta})$ or what ?

Comment: For example when $k=0$ you are talking about $\cos(\sqrt{-a^2})$.

Comment: But K is the variable of integration .